# Cmake building error for Vortex86DX Linux 2.6.23 platform

Tags: cmake

I´m trying to build CMAKE to an embedded platform based on Vortex86DX processor - Linux 2.6.23 kernel.

I´ve downloaded the latest CMAKE package (3.4.1), add did:

`./bootstrap`

Then: `make`

Here is the make result with the error message:

```
$ make
[  1%] Built target cmIML_test
[  4%] Built target cmsys
[  5%] Built target cmsysTestDynload
[  6%] Built target cmsys_c
[  6%] Built target cmsysTestProcess
[  6%] Built target cmsysTestSharedForward
[  7%] Built target cmsysTestsC
[  9%] Built target cmsysTestsCxx
[ 11%] Built target cmzlib
[ 28%] Built target cmcurl
[ 28%] Built target LIBCURL
[ 29%] Built target cmcompress
[ 30%] Built target cmbzip2
[ 40%] Built target cmliblzma
[ 41%] Building C object Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/archive_write_disk_posix.c.o
/home/ftp/pub/cmake-3.4.1/cmake-3.4.1/Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/archive_write_disk_posix.c: In function 'set_time':
/home/ftp/pub/cmake-3.4.1/cmake-3.4.1/Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/archive_write_disk_posix.c:2805:19: error: 'AT_FDCWD' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/ftp/pub/cmake-3.4.1/cmake-3.4.1/Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/archive_write_disk_posix.c:2805:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/ftp/pub/cmake-3.4.1/cmake-3.4.1/Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/archive_write_disk_posix.c:2805:39: error: 'AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[2]: *** [Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/archive_write_disk_posix.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And the system version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux DSC_DKLinux 2.6.23 #6 Mon Sep 1 05:27:54 EDT 2008 i586 unknown
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/gcc-4.7.4/libexec/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/lto-wrapper
Target: i586-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.4/configure --prefix=/usr/gcc-4.7.4 --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.4 (GCC)
```

Comment: Kind of off-topic. Your problem is unrelated to programming, as you only want to compile CMake, isn't it?

Comment: Googling for error message reveals [this mailing](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-11/msg00247.html). Its author assumes problem is that feature set of concrete gcc doesn't include `__USE_ATFILE`.